# .htaccess simple redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I need to do a simple url rewriting in Apache (.htacess better)
The goal is to obtain simplified urls.

`http://www.mysite.com/ana/`  goes to  `http://www.mysite.com/artiste-bio.php?username=ana`

`http://www.mysite.com/john/` goes to  `http://www.mysite.com/artiste-bio.php?username=john`

etc...

so my users have a simplified url : http://www.mysite.com/username/

Except for some folders such as:

```
http://www.mysite.com/images/
http://www.mysite.com/scripts/
http://www.mysite.com/admin/
```

**Is it something that can be done with .htaccess ?**

Regards

Comment: The redirection part is rather easy. The tricky part is how to prevent actual directories from being redirected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent introduction to URL rewriting that I've used in the past:

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

To truly get the most from `.htaccess` URL rewriting though you may need to check out regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be done with .htaccess:

```
# Enable Rewriting  
RewriteEngine on  

# Rewrite user URLs  
#   Input:  user/NAME/  
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME  
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ artiste-bio.php?username=$1
```

This code is extracted from a very good tutorial about mod_rewrite [mod_rewrite in depth](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/artiste-bio.php?username=$1 [L]
```